# Dynamically create button click event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am generating buttons dynamically on page load and on button click event i calling LoadSubClause event which is working fine and with in this event i am creating new buttons. These newly created buttons have LoadDescription event assigned on button click but once i click on any of these buttons it clears the SubClause created buttons and nothing shows up from LoadDescription event.

> 

```
public void LoadSubClause(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    string ClauseName = btn.Text.ToString();
    int counter = 100;

    string query = "select SubClause from Output_DocumentContent where Clause ='" + ClauseName.ToString() + "'";
    Response.Write(query);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Legal;Integrated Security=true");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.Attributes["class"] = "buttonVertical";
        newButton.Text = sdr[0].ToString();
        newButton.ID = "SubClause"+counter.ToString();
        newButton.Click += new EventHandler(LoadDescription);
        //buttons.Add(newButton);
        PanelSubClause.Controls.Add(newButton);
        counter++;
    }
    con.Close();
}
public void LoadDescription(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Load Description Event");
}
```

Comment: try this https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamic-Controls-Made-Easy-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Dynamically created Controls need to be created on every page load, that includes a `PostBack`.

Comment: it will  be great help if you post the code, i tried PostBack but could not make it work,